# Alsa support appears to be broken on MacPro6,1 2013 (black can). Has anyone got this working yet?

Tags: sound, alsa, apple, 17.10

Here's my alsainfo data:
I installed Ubuntu Artful Ardvark on my macpro6,1 late 2013.  no audio

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=e2cb5ba4d9459547142aa6d3d2201c16ab0756a2
Please note I am plugged in to "line out" , not the headphone jack

/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf contains:
options snd-hda-intel model=imac27
I tried auto, generic.. just about all possible combinations.
I can only get audio out of the internal speaker.

Since headphones are detected and they are not.. I plugged in headphones in the headphone jack.  No audio detected.

Does ANYONE have Ubuntu installed on thier macpro6,1 black can with audio working through the audio line out ?

Comment: Here's what I found so far after some troubleshooting.    symptom is lineout plugged in to lineout jack, alsa detects lineout connected  to headphone jack.. and vice versa while audio is directed to the proper port, jack connection is not.  if you connect headphones to the lineout jack and lineout to the headphone jack you will have audio out.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked a fix.  It's actually an issue with the sound hardware on my macpro,6
I was able to fix the audio input/output map.

Comment: Care to share how?  Facing a similar situation...

Comment: Please elaborate on your solution, so others can benefit from it. Thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

I've followed the steps here and it did work: https://lewisinthelandofmachines.tumblr.com/post/662138111279644672/ubuntu-2004-on-2013-trashcan-mac-pro-61

Transcribing in case the website disappears somehow:

```
sudo apt install alsa-tools-gui
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket pulseaudio.service
hdajackretask
```

select "Cirrus Logic CS4208" codec, enable "Parser hints", set "inv_jack_detect" to yes

hit "Apply" then "Install boot override"

```
systemctl --user start pulseaudio.socket pulseaudio.service
```

use headphone socket instead of line out and don't be alarmed at the Toslink red LED
check it's not muted in:

```
alsamixer
```